# How to use and write the value of a vector?

Tags: r, function, readline

I'm using readline function to prompt a user input.

```
A <- readline(prompt = "Question 1: ")

#user inputs for example, "TEST", so Vector A= TEST
```

Then I'll use A  in a function that creates a new vector, but I'd like the new vector to be named TEST instead of A, that is what currently I'm getting.

How can I use the real value of A in a function that creates a new vector?
I need the system to write "TEST" instead of A.

Something like "use A value and write that value (TEST)" not write A, because if not the new vector name created is A and I'd like the vector to be name "TEST".

Is there any command to read and write A value? So it will write TEST.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `assign(A, A)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I have TEST=TEST, but since the user input can be different each time, how  can I put  automatically in the next function   TEST  instead of A (to read TEST)? I need something that will write TEST.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I thought you wanted to match the user input to the object name?  If it is always TEST, then why not just `TEST <- readline(`

Comment: The result of your suggestion is partially correct and sorry if I have not explained very well. The problem is that after using assign (A,A) I use A in a function whose result is a new vector. i.e. function( "A" ) and it creates a new vector called A and I'd need i.e. function ("Value of A"....) so the new vector created automatically is TEST instead of A.  Sorry if I have not explained correctly before.